# dealing with negative square roots in android

Tags: java, android

I am working on a function plotter project for Android in which the user inputs the equation as a string.

this string is solved using the EvalEx library and I get a bunch of data points which I plot using graph-view library.

now the problem is when I give it an equation with negative square root. for example SQRT(1-x) this is causing errors.

```
for( i = 0; i < x.length ; i++) {
     //the equation solver only takes BigDecimal as input.
     x1 = new BigDecimal(x[i]);
     try {
         // eq is the sting that i got from the EditText. 
         y1 = new Expression(eq).with("x", x1).eval();
         y[i] = y1.floatValue();
     } catch(ArithmeticException excp) {
         //these are the data points that go into the plot function
         x[i] = 0;
         y[i] = 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Is your plot supposed to handle imaginary values?

Comment: I updated the question with code. sorry for not being clear.

Comment: what is your exception message? (message in your `excp`)

Comment: the app just crashes.

Comment: @KingPing try to debug your code and find the line which your code raise error on it and check your parameters values.

Comment: Your question is no making sense.  1) The code you posted does not calculate a square root. 2) Yes ... taking the square root of a negative number is an error because the result cannot be represented using `BigDecimal`.  What do you *want* to happen?

Comment: A quick look at the code for EvalEx suggests that it uses its own internal method for calculating square roots. However, I'm not sure what it does if it's presented with a negative argument. From what I can gather it should throw an ArithmeticException, but I wonder if it actually does? There might be an exception in the Android log that will narrow down the problem.

Comment: @KevinBoone negative square root does not give ArithmeticException. the reason I used try() and catch(ArithmeticException excp) is to deal with the error I got when I  divided any number by zero.

Comment: @KingPing you declare `try catch` because of divided by zero but it is also possible that your catch fired because of negative square root.

Comment: @StephenC let me give an example y = SQRT(3 - x^2). in the equation for a given 'X' 'Y' has two values that is (+ve and -ve)SQRT(absoluteValue(3 - x^2)).the input is a string which is converted into an equation and solves it( i used EvalEx library for that). what can I do to get the two outputs?

Comment: @pooyan if the catch fired because of negative square root then there shouldn't be any errors as it will not be solving the said equation.

Comment: You need a parser and a math library that can handle complex numbers. I've often been disappointed how little is available in the area for Java, when there are good implementations for many other languages. If there is anything, ideally open source, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a little unclear what you are trying to do, but I think I understand enough to give you a definitive answer.

Here's the thing:

- The `eval(...)` function returns a single value.

That's what the API says.  That's all it can do.  You cannot avoid that fact.  (There is no magic .....)

So if you want to get both (real) square roots, you need take the positive result returned by `SQRT` and negate it yourself to get the second solution.  In your code.  Something like this:

```
     y1 = new Expression("SQRT(3 - x^2)").with("x", x1).eval();
     y2 = BigDecimal.ZERO - y1;
```

Of course, this is special-case code<sup>1</sup>.  And there is no general-case code that is going to give you multiple solutions to equations when the `SQRT` functions could be anywhere in your expression.

And expressions with complex solutions will be even more intractable with the `EvalEx` API.  You cannot represent a complex solution using the (single) `BigDecimal` that is returned by the `eval` method.  (If you look at the code, taking a square root of a negative number throws the API's `ExpressionException`.)

---

The bottom line is that `EvalEx` is a simple, light-weight expression evaluator.  It is *not designed* for your use-case which involves finding all solutions, and / or dealing with complex numbers.  And making the existing API work for these use-cases would be ... impossible.

But the good news is that the source code for EvalEx is available on GitHub.

- https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx  (I assume this is corresponds to the version you are using.)

You *could* download it and use it as the starting point for writing a *more sophisticated* expression evaluator.

Or ... you could look for an alternative library that does what you need.

---

<sup>1 - That is, it is implemented with the pre-knowledge of what the expression we are evaluating is!  Moreover, it still fails for values of `x` where `3 - x^2` is negative.</sup>